# Why this Xamarin CollectionView doesn't update UI when changing element property?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uicollectionview, inotifypropertychanged

I have a chat application that have a list of chat members which should change property Lida/BgFrame when the last message is seen. Adding new elements to this list works fine, but changing properties of existing elements do nothing.

See my code below(relevant parts only, I have omitted a lot of irrelevant code for this question):

```
namespace MasterDetailPageNavigation.XAML
{

        public static ObservableCollection<ChatMembers> Lista { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ChatMembers>();
        public static ReaderWriterLockSlim valuesLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
        void ObservableCollectionCallback(IEnumerable collection, object context, Action accessMethod, bool writeAccess)
        {
            var collectionLock = (ReaderWriterLockSlim)context;
            Action enterLock = writeAccess ? new Action(collectionLock.EnterWriteLock) : new Action(collectionLock.EnterReadLock);
            Action exitLock = writeAccess ? new Action(collectionLock.ExitWriteLock) : new Action(collectionLock.ExitReadLock);

            enterLock();
            try { accessMethod(); } finally { exitLock(); }
        }



    public class ChatMembers : INotifyPropertyChanged  // THIS IS THE BINDABLE OBJECT
    {
        public Color WhiteAlpha = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        public Color GreenAlpha = new Color(160.0f / 255.0f, 255.0f / 255.0f, 160.0f / 255.0f, 0.2);

        private Guid _talk { get; set; }
        public Guid talk
        {
            get { return _talk; }
            set
            {
                _talk = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("talk");
            }
        }

        private string _Username { get; set; }
        public string Username
        {
            get { return _Username; }
            set
            {
                _Username = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Username");
            }
        }

        private bool _Lida { get; set; }
        public bool Lida
        {
            get { return _Lida; }
            set
            {
                _Lida = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
                FrameBg = !_Lida ? (UserFrom == MainPage.MeuID ? WhiteAlpha : GreenAlpha) : WhiteAlpha;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Lida");
            }
        }

        private Color _FrameBg { get; set; }
        public Color FrameBg
        {
            get { return _FrameBg; }
            set
            {
                _FrameBg = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FrameBg");
            }
        }

        private string _Msg { get; set; }
        public string Msg
        {
            get { return _Msg; }
            set
            {
                _Msg = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Msg");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }



 // Code that updates property "Lida":

   tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
   {
                Color GreenAlpha = new Color(160.0f / 255.0f, 255.0f / 255.0f, 160.0f / 255.0f, 0.2);

                bool itemExists = false;
                valuesLock.EnterReadLock();
                try
                {
                    itemExists = Lista.Any(i => i.talk == guid);
                }
                finally { valuesLock.ExitReadLock(); }

                if (itemExists)
                {
                    ChatMembers item;
                    int indexof;

                    valuesLock.EnterReadLock();
                    try
                    {
                        item = Lista.Single(i => i.talk == guid);
                        indexof = Lista.IndexOf(item);
                    }
                    finally { valuesLock.ExitReadLock(); }

                    _ = Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
                    {
                        valuesLock.EnterWriteLock();
                        try
                        {
                            Lista[indexof].Lida = true;
                            Lista[indexof].FrameBg = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0.7); //desperate try but no success
                        }
                        finally { valuesLock.ExitWriteLock(); }
                    });
                }
            }));

}
```

VIEW CODE BEHIND(relevant part):

```
CollectionViewMembers.BindingContext = MainPage.Lista;
```

VIEW XAML(relevant part):

```
<CollectionView x:Name="CollectionViewMembers" SelectionMode="None"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Padding="6,10,5,1" Margin="0,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="{Binding FrameBg}">
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Evento}" />
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Frame IsClippedToBounds="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="30" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage DownsampleToViewSize="True" HeightRequest="100" IsOpaque="True" Source="{Binding Imagem}" Aspect="AspectFill" LoadingPlaceholder="resource://MasterDetailPageNavigation.shared.icon_default.png" ErrorPlaceholder="resource://MasterDetailPageNavigation.shared.icon_default.png" />
                                    </Frame>
                                                
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="&#xf57d;" TextColor="{Binding ColorOnline}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="15">
                                            <Label.FontFamily>
                                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" Android="Font-Awesome-Free-Solid.otf#FontAwesome5Free-Solid" iOS="FontAwesome5Free-Solid" />
                                            </Label.FontFamily>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Username}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                                        <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Msg}" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                                        <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding DataHora}" FontSize="11" TextColor="#CACACA" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                                <BoxView Margin="0,10,0,0" HeightRequest="0.05" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="#CCE5E5E5"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
           </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

</CollectionView>
```

I also tried to do `Lista[indexOf]=item;` but no UI update.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms.Color constructor takes values between 0..1

Comment: @Jason hey, I'm sorry but I didn't get your point. Can you give more details?

Comment: you are using invalid values when creating your colors.  This may be why nothing appears to change, because it is ignoring the bad values.  ie, `new Color(255, 255, 255, 0.7);`

Comment: @Jason this same object(ChatMembers) has a command that changes BgFrame when the element is tapped(the conversation was openned), it works fine with these colors, I'm able to see an alpha lime green / alpha white background. My problem is when the conversation is already openned and a new message is arrived, I need to set this new msg as readed, it can't be green since it was already seen. But I can't see the change. So, even knowing that colors are working in a different scenario, do you think it can be the color?

Comment: that was the most obvious issue I saw.  Next I would verify that the setter for BgFrame is called and the PropertyChanged handler is firing.

Comment: @Jason the setter for BgFrame is reached and the I've made some tests with these colors and they are being applied. I was able to solve the issue by changing the property "Lida" at the arriving moment of the msg, before it is added/updated.

Comment: @ÉderRocha Why do you set `static` for ObservableCollection<ChatMembers>? And `<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Evento}" />`  command `Evento` is fired? It is used to change chatmember's FrameBg?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT it's static because it's from another page/class, I put everything together here for minifying the question. Yeah, Evento is fired when the element is tapped.